# Advice on using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I would like some advice on good ways to use CompletableFuture.

If I have a list of integers, for each of them, I would like to perform 3 actions, which takes some time. For example, multiply, divide and subtract.

For the result, it should be map, where key is the integer and the value is list that has the result of three actions.

Scenario 1: If I want to write the result to the map once we finish process one integer, then is below the a good way to do it?

```
for (int x : nums) {
  CompletableFuture<Integer> multiply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> multiply(x));
  CompletableFuture<Integer> divide = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> divide(x));
  CompletableFuture<Integer> subtract = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> subtract(x));

  CompletableFuture<Void> allRequests = CompletableFuture.allOf(multiple, divide, substract);

  //iterate the three CompletableFuture and add to the map.
}
```

Scenario 2: If I want to write the result to the map until all the process is done.

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> allRequests = new ArrayList<>();

for (int x : nums) {
  CompletableFuture<Integer> multiply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> multiply(x));
  CompletableFuture<Integer> divide = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> divide(x));
  CompletableFuture<Integer> subtract = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> subtract(x));

  CompletableFuture<Void> allRequestsPerNum = CompletableFuture.allOf(multiple, divide, substract);

  allRequests.add(allRequestsPerNum);
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(allRequest);

//How am I suppose to build the result?
```

For scenario 2, it looks like if we call `CompletableFuture.allOf` inside the for loop, it implies the three actions need to be done before we move to the next number?

Comment: Is this a tutorial exercise in using `CompletableFuture`? Because several even somewhat complex arithmetic calculations will complete faster in the main thread than they will in parallel after you add in the considerable overheads.

Comment: I understand it will add overheads. However, we want to use `CompletableFuture` and evaluate this mechanism in our load test.

Comment: Do you care about the _order_ of the elements of the `List` afterwards, or is the requirement just that it 'contains' them (as stated in the question)?

Comment: @BeUndead Since the result would be map, as long as I can find the result of the input, the order does not matter.

Comment: It's a `Map`, but you said the _value_ of the entries in that `Map` are a `List` of the results of the operations for that `int`.  For example, does the order of the `[1, 2, 3]` in the entry `{1: [1, 2, 3]}` matter to you?

Comment: There are [no best practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164). So you should NOT ask people for them. Just ask your actual question ... and don't ask for someone to bless their answer it by calling it "best practice".  See also: [Why is asking a question on best practices a bad thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the features build into `CompletableFuture`, untested so there are probably some minor problems. It should give you a decent idea.

```
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> allRequests = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int x : nums) {
         allRequests.add(CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> multiply(x)).thenApplyAsync(() -> addToMap()),
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> divide(x)).thenApplyAsync(() -> addToMap()),
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> subtract(x)).thenApplyAsync(() -> addToMap())));
    }
    CompletableFuture.allOf(allRequests.toArray(new CompletableFuture[])).join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work for you:

As mentioned in the comments, I make no promises that there would be any performance benefit from doing things this way.  I also make no promises this is a 'best practice' for doing it.

```
// Keep all the futures around
final Collection<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

// And prepare the resulting map
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int x : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)) {
    // Create the map value List.
    // Initialise it with some default values so that 'set'
    // works.  Use a concurrent-safe List so that there's
    // no risk of corruption from the async operations.
    final List<Integer> value = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0));

    // Put the key and List (not yet ready) into the Map
    map.put(x, value);

    // Add all of your futures to your tracking Collection.
    // Note: each future now includes setting the appropriate
    // entry in the List to that result.
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2 * x)
            .thenAcceptAsync(result -> value.set(0, result)));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2 / x)
            .thenAcceptAsync(result -> value.set(1, result)));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2 - x)
            .thenAcceptAsync(result -> value.set(2, result)));
}

// Wait for them all to complete.
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```